# Skipping restore for project 'SetupWix.wixproj'. The project file may be invalid or missing targets required for restore (NU1503)

Tags: msbuild, wix, nuget-package-restore, wix3.9

We are using Wixtoolset V3.9 to build our setup. We use the following command to start a build:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe" /restore /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64 MySolution.sln /p:BabelEnabled=true
```

We need the parameter `/restore` to restore the nuget-packagages on our build-server. Since we build our Wix-Setup by MSBUILD 16 we get the following warning:

```
Skipping restore for project 'SetupWix.wixproj'. The project file may be invalid or missing targets required for restore.
```

The warning belongs to category [NU1503](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1503) (whatever this means). We cannot find a way to solve or even suppress this warning. We have tried to suppress it by adding the code NU1503 to the Project-Properties:

[image]

Whatever the reason, the warning still appears.

Question: How can we solve or suppress this warning?

Comment: WiX projects usually don't contain any packages, you should skip them from restore

Comment: make sense to share your project references and restore command

Comment: @Pavel Anikhouski: I have added the build-command.

Comment: If you don't have any nuget packages and target in `wixproj`, you can simply suppress this warning using this line `<SuppressSpecificWarnings>1503</SuppressSpecificWarnings>`, or in build tab of your proect

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: We have added the code 1503 into the supression-field of the wix-project, but the warning still appears.

Comment: @Simon Same. In the OP case and in mine, nuget is running on the build server (Azure in my case)

Comment: Did you ever find a way to suppress this warning?

Answer (score 11):

##### TL;DR

You can get rid of `NU1503` by including this in your `.proj` / `msbuild` file:

```xml
  <!-- prevents NU1503 -->
  <Target Name="_IsProjectRestoreSupported"
          Returns="@(_ValidProjectsForRestore)">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_ValidProjectsForRestore Include="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Restore" />
```

Source: https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/537630019c99fdc7bed1b3dfdade72fc3e31692f/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Build.Tasks/NuGet.targets#L1286-L1298

---

##### Detailed explanation

I figured this out by inspecting the `msbuild.binlog` file via `dotnet restore /bl` with the awesome [MSBuild Binary Log File Viewer](https://msbuildlog.com/) tool.

1. The warning is generated by the [`WarnForInvalidProjectTask`](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/537630019c99fdc7bed1b3dfdade72fc3e31692f/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Build.Tasks/NuGet.targets#L313-L317):
   [image]
2. ... which are generated by the [`_FilterRestoreGraphProjectInputItems` target](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/537630019c99fdc7bed1b3dfdade72fc3e31692f/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Build.Tasks/NuGet.targets#L237-L299)...
3. ... which calls a [`_IsProjectRestoreSupported` target](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/537630019c99fdc7bed1b3dfdade72fc3e31692f/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Build.Tasks/NuGet.targets#L292), if there is one.
   [image]

Comment: After adding that XML to my project file (.vcxproj) I get build error: C:\code\IVL-Catheter-Programmer\AuthenticatorAccess\AuthenticatorAccess.vcxproj : error MSB4057: The target "_GenerateRestoreGraphProjectEntry" does
 not exist in the project. ... maybe this solution only works for WIX.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by m0sa lead me to a hopefully easier solution. In [WarnForInvalidProjectTask](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/537630019c99fdc7bed1b3dfdade72fc3e31692f/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Build.Tasks/NuGet.targets#L313-L317) there is a check for *DisableWarnForInvalidRestoreProjects* and you can thereby disable the warning when doing the nuget restore by defining that variable

```
nuget restore /p:DisableWarnForInvalidRestoreProjects="true"
```