# How to filter .wixproj from nuget restore task in yml file?

Tags: nuget, azure-pipelines, wix, nuget-package-restore

In my yml build file I have a nuget task which restores all nuget packages for my sln, however there is a wix project in that sln which is throwing the following error. “NU1503: skipping restore for project ‘project location’ The project file may be invalid or missing targets required for restore”

The .wixproj does not have any nuget packages so I want to be able to ignore this from the nuget restore command task. How would I do this?

Current nuget restore task looks like this…

```
-task: NuGetCommand@2
inputs:
restoreSolution: ‘path/*.sln’
```

Ive tried suppressing the warning in various ways, but hasn’t seemed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following yaml to only restore project with `.csproj`.

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.csproj'
```

You can also refer this similar question [Skipping restore for project 'SetupWix.wixproj'. The project file may be invalid or missing targets required for restore (NU1503)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59785046/16162444).

Comment: Thank you for this. I will try this and see if it works. I did see that similar question, however didn't work for me.